# Difference between two dates in python and mysql workbench

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-workbench

i have date stored on MySQL db i have fetched it using python and added 15 days to it(done successfully), now i have to get difference of that date with current date

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="afif123", db="library")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
date_query = '''SELECT Date from issued_book WHERE Username = 'afif' AND  Book_Code = 12'''
mycursor.execute(date_query)
date_fetch = mycursor.fetchall()
date1 = date_fetch[0]
print(date1)
d1 = date1[0]
diff = d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=15)
dc = diff.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print("diff:", dc)
today1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print("today1:", today1)
day = dc - today1
print(day)
```

i need difference in days(int) so i can calculate the fine

error is showing like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):

(datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 15, 47, 51),)

diff: 2019-05-03

File "C:/Users/shaik/Desktop/lib/d.py", line 16, in

today1: 2019-04-28

day = dc - today1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the difference, you have to use datetime.datetime object. Then when you subtract, you get a timedelta object.

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="afif123", db="library")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
date_query = '''SELECT Date from issued_book WHERE Username = 'afif' AND  Book_Code = 12'''
mycursor.execute(date_query)
date_fetch = mycursor.fetchall()
date1 = date_fetch[0]
print(date1)
d1 = date1[0]
diff = d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=15)
dc = diff.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print("diff:", dc)

# Below is the updated piece from your code
today1 = datetime.datetime.today() 
print("today1:", today1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
delta = diff - today1
print(delta.days)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks it worked, but there is warning showing up on today1 (at diff - today1)  it says expected type 'timedelta', got 'datetime instead'. otherwise i got what i needed

Comment: That seems weird, things should be fine till the time both the operands are of the same type either 'datetime' or 'timedelta'